# Perl HTML::TreeBuilder incorrect parsing

Tags: html, perl, dom

I have the following code, which uses [`HTML::TreeBuilder`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder) to parse the HTML from a web site.

```
 my $urlToSpider = "http://www.yelp.com/biz/selden-standard-detroit";
 my $html = get $urlToSpider;

 $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
 #print $html;
 $tree->parse($html);

 print $tree->as_HTML;
```

In the above example, when I save `print $tree->as_HTML` to file, the HTML structure is different from the original structure, although `print $html` gives the correct structure.

Why is the module parsing incorrectly?

Comment: How/what it parses incorrectly? (you probably don't want from us to parse and compare 400kb html?)

Comment: You shouldn't expect the round-trip conversion to match. Is there a reason why you need it to be identical?

Answer (score 1):

What you are calling *incorrect parsing* is simply mismatching round-trip conversion. The result of the `as_HTML` method is highly unlikely to match the source data because it is meant only to be *equivalent* to the original HTML.

There will be differences because of, but not limited to these reasons

- HTML data can contain *insignificant whitespace* which has no effect on what is rendered in the browser. `HTML::TreeBuilder` doesn't store that whitespace and won't reproduce it
- `HTML::TreeBuilder` is highly tolerant of errors in the original HTML, and is meant to behave similarly to real web browsers in the wild. So anything that isn't strictly valid HTML will be represented as a valid interpretation of the same data

For instance, if I write

```
say HTML::TreeBuilder->new->parse('<p>text</p>')->as_HTML;
```

I get the output

```
<html><head></head><body><p>text</body></html>
```

So the module has recognized that the complete document should include `<html>`, `<head>`and `<body>` elements, which is fine for all normal applications of HTML data.

Comment: There are also non-errors (like tag/attribute name capitalisation and optional start and end tags) which get normalised.

Comment: @Quentin: Yes, there are several such equivalents. You are welcome to edit my post if you think you can make it more useful